# Vtiger cannot filter by created date

Tags: vtiger

Could you please help me a bug in Vtiger. In the past, this is not happened.

i have tried to input from date to date in created date column and click search in Opportunities module. But system has throwned permission issue:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Thanks,
Victor

Comment: Please provide more details with screenshot and what you tried to solve

Comment: Hi, Please help me on this. the step is;

Comment: Hi, Please help me on this. the step as screenshot when i do search by created date in Vtiger. I'm using version 6.5.0. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2IAEVIaArrdRlhINkFGRUx6dkU

Comment: I am not able to open this image. You can update question here with image

Comment: Did you tried to check logs

Comment: HI, Could you please view the image again. i checked the log already. But there is not anything insight. Thanks.

Comment: Is all your directory have 755 and files have 644 permissions set? If not then its permission issue. I never faced this kind of error before so may be assuming its permission issue

Comment: The permission is ok. I also didn't get this issue in the past. I just got it some days ago.

Comment: Then there might be issue at code level which i can't check from here. You only have to debug line by line and have to find the issue. Try echo exit line by line and check where it stops.